# TwitteR r package: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4: version `CURL_OPENSSL_3' not found

Tags: r, twitter-oauth, libcurl, ubuntu-18.04

I have updated my OS to Ubuntu 18.04 recently and twitteR R package is not working anymore.

I am having the following error message during `setup_twitter_oauth`.

```
> setup_twitter_oauth(api_key,api_secret)
[1] "Using browser based authentication"
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
  unable to load shared object '/home/my-laptop/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/curl/libs/curl.so':
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4: version `CURL_OPENSSL_3' not found (required by /home/my-laptop/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/curl/libs/curl.so)
```

I was trying to install `libcurl3`. But the installation process wants to remove my r installation as well as `libcurl4`. This is what I get,

```
my-laptop:~$ sudo apt-get install libcurl3
[sudo] password for my-laptop: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  cdbs dh-translations fonts-mathjax intltool jq libblas-dev libc-ares2
  libhttp-parser2.7.1 libjq1 libjs-bootstrap libjs-highlight.js
  libjs-jquery-datatables libjs-jquery-metadata libjs-jquery-tablesorter
  libjs-mathjax libjs-twitter-bootstrap liblapack-dev libncurses5-dev
  libnlopt0 libonig4 libquantlib0v5 libreadline-dev libtinfo-dev libuv1
  node-highlight.js nodejs nodejs-doc python3-scour r-doc-html scour
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libcurl4 r-base r-base-core r-base-dev r-base-html r-cran-boot r-cran-class
  r-cran-cluster r-cran-codetools r-cran-foreign r-cran-kernsmooth
  r-cran-lattice r-cran-mass r-cran-matrix r-cran-mgcv r-cran-nlme r-cran-nnet
  r-cran-rpart r-cran-spatial r-cran-survival r-recommended
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libcurl3
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 21 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/214 kB of archives.
After this operation, 60,0 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

Any idea how to solve this problem?

My `session.info()` is as follows,

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/libblas.so.3.7.1
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack/liblapack.so.3.7.1

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=de_DE.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=de_DE.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=de_DE.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=de_DE.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] twitteR_1.1.9

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] bit_1.1-12     httr_1.3.1     compiler_3.4.4 rjson_0.2.15   R6_2.2.2       DBI_0.8        tools_3.4.4   
 [8] yaml_2.1.18    bit64_0.9-7    openssl_1.0.1
```

Comment: Have you tried to reinstall the R package `curl`?

Comment: Yes. I removed the curl package, reinstall libcurl14-openssl-dev and then installed those two again. It works now. Could you please add your advice as an answer? I will mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The R package `curl` was compiled against `libcurl3`, which is no longer installed. If you reinstall the `curl` package, it compiles against the installed `libcurl4`, provided the necessary development packages are installed. Alternatively you can use the [pre-compiled package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/r-cran-curl).

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar error when trying to publish HTML from RStudio to RPubs.

Reinstalling `curl` didn't solve the issue for me, but this did the trick:

`install.packages("RCurl")`